# Generate waveform image from audio stream of a video

Tags: java, audio, video, stream, xuggler

I need to generate a waveform of an audio stream of a video,
currently I'm using xuggler and java to do some little things, but seems like I'm not able to get a byte array of the inputstream audio of my video from IAudioSamples.

Now I'm searching for an easier way to do it since xuggler is really becoming hard to understand, I've searched online and I've found this:
http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/

should work on .wav files, but when I try the code on a video or a .mp3 the AudioInputStream returns "cannot find an audio input stream"

can someone tell me a way to get byte[] array of the audiostream of one video so that I can follow the tutorial to create a waveform?
also if you have suggestion or other library that could help me I would be glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because mp3 it's an encoded format, you'll need before to decode it to get ray data (bytes) from it.

```
class Mp3FileXuggler {

private boolean DEBUG = true;

private String _sInputFileName;
private IContainer _inputContainer;
private int _iBitRate;
private IPacket _packet;
private int _iAudioStreamId;
private IStreamCoder _audioCoder;

private int _iSampleBufferSize;
private int _iInputSampleRate;

private static SourceDataLine mLine;

private int DECODED_AUDIO_SECOND_SIZE = 176375; /** bytes */
private int _bytesPerPacket;

private byte[] _residualBuffer;

/**
 * Constructor, prepares stream to be readed
 * @param input input File
 * @throws UnsuportedSampleRateException 
 */
public Mp3FileXuggler(String sFileName) throws UnsuportedSampleRateException{
    this._sInputFileName = sFileName;
    this._inputContainer = IContainer.make();
    this._iSampleBufferSize = 18432;
    this._residualBuffer = null;

    /** Open container **/
    if (this._inputContainer.open(this._sInputFileName, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not read the file: " + this._sInputFileName);

    /** How many streams does the file actually have */
    int iNumStreams = this._inputContainer.getNumStreams();
    this._iBitRate = this._inputContainer.getBitRate();

    if (DEBUG) System.out.println("Bitrate: " + this._iBitRate);

    /** Iterate the streams to find the first audio stream */
    this._iAudioStreamId = -1;
    this._audioCoder = null;
    boolean bFound = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < iNumStreams && bFound == false){

        /** Find the stream object */
        IStream stream = this._inputContainer.getStream(i);
        IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

        /** If the stream is audio, stop looking */
        if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO){
            this._iAudioStreamId = i;
            this._audioCoder = coder;
            this._iInputSampleRate = coder.getSampleRate();
            bFound = true;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    /** If none was found */
    if (this._iAudioStreamId == -1)
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find audio stream in container: " + this._sInputFileName);

    /** Otherwise, open audiocoder */

    if (this._audioCoder.open(null,null) < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("could not open audio decoder for container: " + this._sInputFileName);

    this._packet = IPacket.make();

    //openJavaSound(this._audioCoder);

    /** Dummy read one packet to avoid problems in some audio files */
    this._inputContainer.readNextPacket(this._packet);


    /** Supported sample rates */
    switch(this._iInputSampleRate){
        case 22050:
                this._bytesPerPacket = 2304;
            break;

        case 44100:
                this._bytesPerPacket = 4608;
            break;


    }

}

public byte[] getSamples(){
    byte[] rawBytes = null;


        /** Go to the correct packet */
        while (this._inputContainer.readNextPacket(this._packet) >= 0){
            //System.out.println(this._packet.getDuration());
            /** Once we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to the audio stream */

            if (this._packet.getStreamIndex() == this._iAudioStreamId){
                IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(this._iSampleBufferSize, this._audioCoder.getChannels());


                //  System.out.println(">> " + samples.toString());
                /** Because a packet can contain multiple set of samples (frames of samples). We may need to call
                 * decode audio multiple times at different offsets in the packet's data */

                int iCurrentOffset = 0;
                while(iCurrentOffset < this._packet.getSize()){

                    int iBytesDecoded = this._audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, this._packet, iCurrentOffset);
                    iCurrentOffset += iBytesDecoded;

                    if (samples.isComplete()){
                        rawBytes = samples.getData().getByteArray(0, samples.getSize());

                        //playJavaSound(samples);
                    }
                }
                return rawBytes;
            }
            else{
                /** Otherwise drop it */
                do{}while(false);
            }
        }

    return rawBytes; /** This will return null at this point */
}
```

}

Use this class in order to get the raw data from a mp3 file, and with them feed your spectrum drawer.